# Unpickling Error while using Word2Vec.load()

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to load a binary file using `gensim.Word2Vec.load(fname)` but I get the error:

> File "file.py", line 24, in 
>       model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('ammendment_vectors.model.bin')
>
> File "/home/hp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1396, in load
>       model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/hp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 271, in load
>       obj = unpickle(fname)
>
> File "/home/hp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 933, in unpickle
>       return _pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
>
> _pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK

I googled but I am unable to figure out why this error is coming up. Please let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would normally work, if the file was created by gensim's native `.save()`.

Are you sure the file `'ammendment_vectors.model.bin'` is complete and uncorrupted?

Was it created using the same Python/gensim versions as in use where you're trying to `load()` it?

Can you try re-creating the file?